# Billinear Interpolation of 3 points

Tags: linear-algebra

I have three points $ (2,2)$ ,  $(1,0)$  and $ (4,0) $

With the values $0$, $0.5$ and $1$

Now with the help of billinear interpolation, my task is to calculate the value for the point at $(2,1)$

I dont know if i did it the right way. But first of all i calculated the distance between the points of the triangle and the point, wich value i want to have. And multiplied them by their values:

$$ \sqrt{(2-2)²+(2-1)²}*0 + \sqrt{(2-1)²+(0-1)²}*0.5+\sqrt{(2-4)²+(1-0)²}*1 =2.943$$

Next i divided this sum through the value of all distances:

$$1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}= 4.65028$$
$$2.943/4.65028=0.632866$$

No my question is: Is the result correct and did i use the right formula? Thanks

Comment: use ideas in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation

Comment: @janmarqz yes i saw this article! But i didnt know how to do this with three points! Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: wow! this problem is making me sweat (+1) :D

Comment: The Wikipedia page on bilinear interpolation requires 4 points arranged so that just 4 values define the 4 needed coordinates (ie, each of the values "left", right", "top", "bottom" appear twice in the 8 values comprising the 4 coordinate points). A solution using that approach can be done if we designate the missing left top point at (1,2) to have weight L and the other missing point at (4,2) to have weight -2L. In this case, calculating R2 (see wikipedia) gives (2,2) with weight 0.0 as stated in the OP. Using the lower 2 points gives R1 at (2,0) with weight 2/3. These lead to 1/3 at (2,1).

Comment: ..However in general the L value does not factor out. For example, if we had wanted the weight (the interpolated value) associated with (3/2, 1/4), we would get (49+6L)/96  (if I didn't make a mistake). So it happens we can solve the OP problem precisely because (2,1) is directly below (2,2) but generally could not without more information.. if we want to use bilinear interpolation which is defined on 4 points.

Comment: We can note that each of the two approaches given below (from Jan 2015) also give 1/3 as an answer. Each seems to be linear in x as well as in y independently. janmarqz's solution is better if we want to consider new points since f(X,Y) = AX+BY+C and all 5 values would be known (A=1/6, B=-1/3, C=1/3). sid's approach is sufficient if we want to perhaps vary up the weight values but still look at (2,1) for the interpolated value so that we don't have to recalculate a new barycentric coord. The OP's approach is most likely incorrect; it diminishes most the contribution from the nearest vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $3$ points, it's better to use [barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system). Basically you can express any point $(x, y)$ on or inside a triangle $(x_0, y_0)$, $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ as:
$$
(x, y) = (1 - u - v )(x_0,y_0) + u(x_1,y_1) + v(x_2,y_2)
$$
where $u,v \in \left[0,1\right]$ and $u + v \leq 1$. With this scheme, the interpolation is guaranteed to be linear.

Comment: Thanks! But i dont really get the formula! Espacially u and v for what they stand for! Could you maybe explain it futher? Thanks

Comment: I think OP seeks a bilinear $f(v)=v^{\top}Av$ which matches at three points and predicts $f(2,1)$, right @JohnSmith?

Comment: @JohnSmith: like I said, $u$ and $v$ are numbers that vary between $0$ and $1$, with the special criterion that $u+v \leq 1$. The idea is that with proper choices of $u$ and $v$, you can obtain any point that lies within the triangle. The equation was basically shorthand for:
$$
x = (1-u-v)x_0 + u x_1 + v x_2 \\
y = (1-u-v)y_0 + u y_1 + v y_2
$$

Comment: Bilinear is neither linear nor affine

Comment: @janmarqz yes i want the value that is at f(2,1)! Is this not the right approach?

Comment: @janmarqz: Couldn't a linear and affine formulation for the same thing be done in this manner?
$$
\boldsymbol{x} = (1-\alpha)\boldsymbol{x}_0 + \alpha \left[(1-\beta)\boldsymbol{x}_1 + \beta \boldsymbol{x}_2\right]
$$
where $0 \leq \alpha,\beta \leq 1$. All I'm doing is using  $u$ and $v$ instead of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. 
Sorry if I've misunderstood, my solutions tend to be more intuitive than rigorous!

Comment: @sid: my point was set 5 commentaries above.

Comment: Six years later... using OP's order for the points, (2,2), (1,0), and (4.0), we would get 1-u-v=1/2, u=1/3, and v=1/6. If we then apply those coefficients to the weights, we get the interpolated value at (2,1) - - - > > > 1/2(0.0) + 1/3(0.5) + 1/6(1.0) = 1/3. This solution above does not currently but should state that these coefficients are to be applied to the 3 endpoint values (aka, weights) to get the final interpolated answer at (2,1).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are seeking a function $f=f(x,y)$ with three prescribed values, then an interpolating function for this three data will determine an **unique plane** in 3-space.

Planes as a graphic of a functions are of the form
$$f(x,y)=Ax+By+C. \qquad(1)$$

In another hand functions like
$$f(x,y)=Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F,\qquad (2)$$
are the result of developing quadratic maps of the form 
$$v\mapsto v^{\top}Qv\quad \mbox{or}\quad v\mapsto v^{\top}Qv+K,\qquad(3)$$
where $v=(x,y)$, $Q$ is a two-by-two matrix and $K$ a constant.

Now, meanwhile a value $f(2,1)$ is not given, then it is impossible to determine an unique function of the types in $(3)$.

So, we are bounded to use type $(1)$.  Your conditions can be written as
$$\begin{aligned}
0.5&=f(1,0)=A+C,\\
1&=f(4,0)=4A+C\\
0&=f(2,2)=2A+2B+C\;,
\end{aligned}$$

Which can easily be solved and then one can establish the value for $f(2,1)$ that you are searching.

**Remark:** Sid was in the right track but failed to say the form of $f$.

Comment: in the end there wasn't too much sweat, what did delay me was the Baltimore vs NE 's game.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to calculate it and then come back to you!

Comment: Six years after the OP, it's probably safe to say for equation (1) that A=1/6, B=-1/3, C=1/3. So f(2,1) = 1/6(2)-1/3(1)+1/3 = 1/3. I'm not sure if the discussion for equation (2) and (3) are correct, but (1) is linear in x and y and works well. We can sanity check that f(1,0)=1/2, f(4,0)=1, and f(2,2)=0. Minus the diversion into eqns (2) and (3), I suggest this be the chosen solution instead of sid's (which is also alright but does not take as direct an approach).

Comment: @Jose_X give me the chance to retake the thread of the six year ago and two hours ideas